# How do I reduce the resolution of a video when working with the node editor?

Tags: video

Working with 4k source material, rendering takes forever. To get a feel for the results, I set the resolution to 1/4 in x and y direction (and the frame step to 4).

I now get the center quarter of my video rendered instead of the full frames.

I tried to compensate this by adding a scaling filter but that applied after the scene was cropped.

See the [image: low res]. I want the "Viewer Node" view rendered to 960x540 but I get the "Render Result".

I suppose it should work somehow without the extra filter but can't find it in an hour now.

Edit: Changing the "Percentage Scale for Render Resolution" to 50% breaks the result in a similar way:

[image: scaled]

Edit 2: I used the node editor, not the video sequence editor! With the Video Sequence Editor all is fine but I need the node editor.

[image: the node editor is being used]

Comment: You cloud simply render and 50% or 25% resolution with the percent slider under the render frame size settings

Comment: Thank you Duarte for your quick reply but reducing the slider leads to cropping in the "Render Result" view, too. Is this a bug? Might this have to do with the "Speed" filter?

Comment: Hum that is strange, it does sound unusual. Not very familiar with the video editor myself, but that doesn't look much like standard Blender behavior. Maybe someone else knows, otherwise might be a bug, and hence worth reporting to the tracker.

Comment: ~~Seams to be a bug and given I run a two years old version of Blender (Yeah, thank you Debian, what's the hold-up!?, I guess I should suspend this Q until update is installed. Sorry.)~~

Comment: Same issue on Blender 2.78, at least when loading from the other `.blend` file.

Comment: Try with a fresh file on a fresh 2.8 without any filters or things that may get in the way of diagnose. If problem persists then its time to report a bug. Also try the image *Distort > Scale* node, see if it solves the problem

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug related to the nodes editor. Tried a fresh file. Same result but only with node editor. See edits.